# How to render a simple list in ember.js handlebars template with each helper?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, each, helper

I got a deprecation warning on `{{#each}}` saying I should switch to `{{#each items in items}}` but I can't make it work.

http://jsbin.com/qeqeyazoci/2/edit?html,js,output

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look iterate through `content` instead of `items`

`{{#each item in content}}`